# How to move files(including apps) to an adopted sd card directly from PC?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, files, adoptable-storage

I don't really know how to make a title for this and it might be somewhat far and my english is not on point but please understand.

I have a 16gb SD card that is formatted as an adopted internal storage and an internal of 1gb (**4gb originally, but OS occupies 3.4gb or something and built-in apps [which I can't move to the adopted. I don't know why]**). My ways of getting data onto my phone is via the USB cable to PC/Laptop, but since the PC/laptop can't read the SD card, it only shows the 1gb internal. Let's say I want to move a larger file; 2gb, how can I make it possible? Any more ways to move files? 

 
Anyways, Shareit (a file-sharing app, available on pc) is my last resort but I feel that via the USB cable is faster.

Device: **Lenovo A7000-a** 
**Android 6.0** (just updated. Reformated everything since apps cant be read because all my data(including app data/files/obb) was on the sd card and it needs to be an adopted to be capable of reading app files.)

Comment: Out of curiosity: is reverting to Lollipop not an option?

Comment: I'm not really techy and, to be honest, I don't know how to revert back, and I fear that I will just destroy the device. The system updated and I thought it may be best because (maybe) future updates will be on about Android M, leaving Lollipop to be somewhat abandoned. 
Again, I'm not techy and I probably don't know what I'm talking about. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

So your SD card has a certain format. This allows it to be used for apps, but the downside is your Windows doesn't see it. In theory a good driver should present the SD card over MTP, but that's wishful thinking.

The best way to access your SD is via adb. Install adb on Windows and **push** your files over USB. This requires typed commands in a shell.

You might also be able to see your SD when connecting your phone to a Linux system.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you need to do after selecting sd card as internal storage: Go to settings then Storage and sd card. Open menu and tap migrate data. This will Transfer app data, books etc to sd card from internal storage, making sd card as default write basically. Also you can access SD card now. Cheers! Lenevo A7000 user.